# Apache Subdomain using Codeigniter framework without having multiple copies

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

Im trying to figure out if theres a means of using everything I developed in three instances. I have three primary loading points for a piece of software I am developing. One is a Desktop version thats friendly for browsers on desktops/laptops/most tablets. Then I have one that is geared towards mobile browsers and other tablets. Lastly I have one thats purely for API usage, no views or anything just completely raw data in JSON, XML, or CSV formats. Each piece independently works fine.

But I'd like to contain the individual controllers for each ones needs separated by some degree.

What I have done to date for organizational purposes is have controller file names be something like `desktop_name-of-controller.php`, `mobile_name-of-controller.php`, `api_name-of-controller.php` And with routes I point to the respective controller in such a fashion like

```
$route['login'] = 'desktop_login';
$route['m/login'] = 'mobile_login';
$route['api/login'] = 'api_login';
```

which works, but some people I am working with/for would like to use subdomains ie:
api.example.com, m.example.com. And the only way I can gather to do this is, litterally have 3 copies of the CI install I am running currently with the routes the way I have them. Just to do a sub domain setup like they would like. I am hoping to find a way to circumvent this and work around it so I can in a sense maybe through some `mod_rewrite` magic, or `htaccess` magic, or some form of magic make this work without having to have said 3 copies, so I am open to ideas cause I am at a loss.

Comment: Can you have virtual subdomains? Checkout this link http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/89424/

Comment: That sir is indeed, an awesome find. That is in part up to spec with what I think it is I need to do, I just need to sort the concept out some in my head, and when I get sometime this weekend actually play with the idea, hopefully something comes of it thats a good thing, either that I some how manage to set my remote server on fire from beating it up to much, and they call me from the datacenter all angry like.. we shall see, thank you.

Comment: curious, if you used a search engine for that, what was the keywords/phrase you used, I may want to look for some more like postings to help me achieve my goal

Comment: I am glad it helped. I have used CodeIgniter in the past with different folders (e.g. example.com/admin mapping to controllers in /application/controllers/admin) and I figured it must be a way to link to subdomains easily. I googled for `codeigniter subdomains`

Comment: thats all there was, I looked for that myself before coming here, and my results were crap, luck of the draw I suppose. Either way thank you again